# Lazarus SimpleServer

Tags: sockets, lazarus

I would like to create a Simple Socket Server in Lazarus, using the built in TSimpleIPCServer. **I do not want to use any other framework or product !**
There seem to be no documentation on this Component. I have looked all over the Net but I could not find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

But IPC isn't a Simple Socket library it is provide memory sharing to another application. Also in Windows 7 and above isn't easy to communicate with fpc's IPC server.
My advise use or change that software/library:
http://torry.net/vcl/system/appscommunications/ipc.zip

It is working I tested with delphi but for windows it can be compile in lazarus.